# WebView not load when open one url(android)

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, webview

Sorry for my english. I have one activity and one fragment(fragment have webView). In activity i have items menu, if i click for item reload link in fragment. Each time when i click for item in menu, i call this code

```
ItemMenuFragment fragment = new ItemMenuFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Fragment reload and then he get new link for webView. In fragment load page html like this

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl(Global.URL_MAIN + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getLink());
```

Everything work fine. But in html link i have profile page, in this profile page i have button "load image", when i click this button show popup and after this all items menu cant load url. Its show white page and its all.

**My ways of solving:**

I think, need reload my fragment every times and i add this code when load fragment:

```
ItemMenuFragment fragment = new ItemMenuFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if(!fragmentTransaction.isEmpty()) fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

its not work, then i add this code:

```
ItemMenuFragment fragment = new ItemMenuFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
fragmentTransaction.attach(fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It does not work either. Then I add in fragment code, which the clean webView:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
```

It does not work either. I don't know how to solve my problem. Once again about my problem: after popup window in webView i cant any more load url in webView. It show me white pages.

**UPD:**

This is simple code my project. My left menu create dynamicly and in left menu i have listView. I have only one fragment, this fragment reload link each time when i click some item in menu

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //menuItems - listview
                //item - object in menu(contains link and name)
                //adapterMenuItems adapter for lisView

                menuItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {
                        setLink(item.getUrl());
                        setFragment();
                        adapterMenuItems.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(menu.isMenuShowing()) menu.toggle();
                    }
                });
        }

    public void setFragment(){
            ItemMenuFragment fragment = new ItemMenuFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

            //set link for fragment
            public void setLink(String link){
                this.link = link;
            }

            //return link for fragment
            public String getLink(){
                return link;
            }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ItemMenuFragment extends Fragment { 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View containerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_menu, container, false);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.loadUrl(Global.URL_MAIN + ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getLink());
}}
```

Comment: Please show which class and method contain each code fragment. The easiest way to do this is simply enclose each code snippet in a class and method declaration.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for answer, i udapte my qestion

Comment: Please edit the original code snippets. Just adding more code at the end of your question makes things more confusing.

Comment: Also please include the `class ...` lines from your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry for my confusing code, i try add clear piece of code. I update